# Is the sorting of answers on meta broken?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers

For some meta questions, the answers show up in a different order than by votes. That seems like a bug. This is on Google Chrome 25.0.1364.68 in linux.

[image: example screenshot]

The screenshot is from [this question](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1682/should-i-answer-my-own-questions-immediately). Another example is [this one](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/please-zap-the-meta-tags-and-dependent-tags), where the order of answers is: one with 0 votes, 2 votes, 3, 2, 6.

I would think this would have been caught before, which suggests that: either it's something local to my system, or: it's intentional and meta works very differently from how I would think it does...

Comment: Is the sort order by chance set to "oldest"? I swear I every now and then see that get reset somehow (maybe I just accidentally click on it, who knows).

Comment: I really do think that the unless you have an order picked the default is now random order... or my chrome and I.E. are broken as well.

Comment: @sarge_smith which tab is it saying?

Comment: @Erik please check which tab it has selected

Comment: @MarcGravell I have no tab selected, and no tab is highlighted with the little box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your sort order:

[image: Answer sorting]

It's fine on my end.

Comment: Ah excellent - I was fully aware of the sorting controls in the *questions* screen, but for some reason was completely blind to the sorting controls in the *answers* section. Fixed!

Comment: Don't worry, it's a common mistake, seen it a bunch of times on Meta Stack Overflow. I hate the UI, there's no visual distinction at all, but there it is.